# How to xtract multiple numbers delimited by brackets from a txt document into a python list?

Tags: python, list, text, text-extraction

So I have a .txt file which looks like the following:

```
[some_strings] id:[1227194]
[some_strings] id:[1227195]
[some_strings] id:[1227196]
```

What I need to do is to extract all the numbers in between the brackets [] and append them in a list which I will then use for further analysis.
The final result should then be:

```
list = [1227194,1227195,1227196]
```

What would be the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Hugo, Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), How to Ask, and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import re

filename = 'text.txt'

with open(filename) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    lines = " ".join(line.rstrip() for line in lines)    
    num_list = re.findall('\d+',lines)
num_list
```

output:

```
['1227194', '1227195', '1227196']
```

Answer (score 0):

regex explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/YJxmfc/1)

```py
import re

s = """[some_strings] id:[1227194]
[some_strings] id:[1227195]
[some_strings] id:[1227196]"""

l = re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]', s, re.MULTILINE)
print(l) #['1227194', '1227195', '1227196']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split`, another way would be to use regex:

```
s = """
[some_strings] id:[1227194]
[some_strings] id:[1227195]
[some_strings] id:[1227196]
"""

[line.rstrip(']').split('[')[-1] for line in s.split('\n') if line != '']
# Out[95]: ['1227194', '1227195', '1227196'
```

Answer (score 0):

A way I think would be:

```
ids = []
with open(text.txt) as file:
   for line in file.readlines():
       id_with_bracket = split('id:[')
       ids.append(int(id_with_bracket[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = re.findall('\d+',f.read())


['1227194', '1227195', '1227196']
```